# Picker with two selection columns with numbers in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, timepicker, picker

I need to make a picker like this in the picture below:

[image]

What you see is a TimePicker and I took it just to give you an example. I would like to have one with about 200 numbers on the left and 100 on the right (for example). How can I do it in a Xamarin.Forms PCL project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem you'll face is that the picker control you see here is a native iOS control. The Xamarin.Forms [TimePicker](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker/) is basically not a physical control in itself but it translates to a native control on each platform. That's why it will look different on Android and UWP devices because they provide their own picker controls, as seen in the picture below.

[image]

Now, if you're ok with the controls looking different, you could use [custom renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) to modify each native control or even replace them to provide the functionality you need. I thought I'd outline the basic steps for you to get you started:

1. Create a new Xamarin.Forms control called CustomPicker or something.
2. Create custom renderers for each platform.
3. On iOS, you can use the [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview) and specify [numberOfComponents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview/1614368-numberofcomponents), [numberOfRows](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview/1614381-numberofrows) and the data source.
4. On Android, you might want to use a 3rd party control since by default, there are no scrolling picker controls like the one on iOS. [WheelPicker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker) looks promising.
5. On UWP, you might be able to work something out using the [PickerFlyoutBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.PickerFlyoutBase). I have limited knowledge on the platform but you should be able to find something quite easily.

As you can see, it's going to be quite an effort to get the scroll picker working on each platform.

---

Edit: You could also look into native embedding, which lets you embed native controls into Xamarin.Forms app's pages.

[Native Embedding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/add-platform-controls/)

[Embedding native controls into Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/embedding-native-controls-into-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

We've developed a two-column picker for Xamarin.Forms (Android and iOS).

Sample:
https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/MaterialDesignControlsPlugin#materialdoublepicker

Screenshots:
[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXaa7.png)
[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwGiN.png)

We added this control to MaterialDesignControls NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.MaterialDesignControls/), where you can find other interesting controls with the material design look and feel.

Contributions are welcome!